# MVC routing constraint gives 404 error when false

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, constraints

I'm getting a 404 page when a constraint is not satisfied, I thought once the constraint is false it would move to the next route. Anyway to have this go to the next route instead of giving a 404 error?

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
      name:="rewrites", _
      url:="{*permalink}", _
      defaults:=New With {.controller = "Pages", .action = "rewrites", .id = UrlParameter.Optional},
      constraints:=New With {.permalink = New urlConstraint()} _
  )


    routes.MapRoute( _
        name:="Default", _
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )






Public Function Match(httpContext As System.Web.HttpContextBase, route As System.Web.Routing.Route, parameterName As String, values As System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary, routeDirection As System.Web.Routing.RouteDirection) As Boolean Implements System.Web.Routing.IRouteConstraint.Match

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(values(parameterName)) Then
        If Not values.ContainsKey(parameterName) Then Return False
        Dim permalink As String = UCase(values(parameterName).ToString())
        Return Db.Routes.Any(Function(a) a.StaticUrl.ToUpper() = permalink)

    End If


    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an example of unreasoned API: interface for **route parameter** constraint is named as `IRouteConstraint` and might mistakenly be considered as a constraint which matches request's Url with route, although it validates only route parameter **after** the MVC's Route Engine already found **matched route**.

The answer for your question: when route constraint is invoked, the framework considers that **route is found**. And now the framework transits to further step - route constraints checking. `IRouteConstraint` can say to framework that parameter is not valid (`Match` method returns `false`) and so there is no action to handle the request, even if action actually exists... This situation is considered as HTTP handler not found - the framework sends `Http 404`, in spite of it found a route.

Here you can ask a legitimate question: *why the framework does not throw `Http 400` - Bad Request?*  Maybe because action was not invoked..?  It is another story)